# INDEXOF returning "Scalars can be only used with projections" error

Tags: apache-pig

Am trying to find whether one field is sub string of another field by using INDEXOF(f1,f2) > -1 where f1,f2 are both char arrays. But am getting error message as "Scalars can be only used with projections".

 Is this error message because of, lack of support for two variables comparison in INDEXOF or something else?  Can some one help with this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post your full code.

Comment: There are many errors which can cause the "scalars can only be used with projections" message.  It's not the INDEXOF command causing the problem.